# How can I click an OK button in a modal window using selenium with java?

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a script for a website I am currently working on.

I tried using `xpath` and `cssSelector` but it's not finding the button. I have a class name but it's with spaces.

**HTML code for the button:**

[image: HTML code for the button]

I have used `Thread.Sleep(3000)`.
Here is the `cssSelector` code for it:

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ui_modal_1505889041536 > div.actions > div.ui.approve.positive.button")).click();
```

And here is the `xpath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui_modal_1505889041536\"]/div[3]/div[2]")).click();
```

The error I am receiving when using the cssSelector:

[image]

Comment: What did you try ? where is the code using cssSelector?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ui_modal_1505889041536 > div.actions > div.ui.approve.positive.button")).click();

Comment: Update the same in the question please. Also share the element inspection in the question for the same element.

Comment: Alright, thank you. This is my first time on StackOverflow.

Comment: Welcome. Its good to share what you've tried since that helps other understand the problem quickly.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Try this code and lets see if it works - `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui_modal_1505889041536\"]/div[3]/div[2]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Comment: try css locator:   div.modal  div.actions > div.approve  And I think the id : ui_modal_150588904153‌​6 should  be a change value. not recommend to us it.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use the following xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui_modal_1505889041536']//*[text()='ok']").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this answer:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui approve positive button']")).click();
```

This works ! Thanks for all your help guys!